# JQuery - Iterate a collection of value

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a collection of data:

```
q: "5,1,3,4"
```

I need to get those values and so I can have checkbox preselected

```
$('input[data-value=5]').prop('checked', true);
$('input[data-value=1]').prop('checked', true);
$('input[data-value=3]').prop('checked', true);
$('input[data-value=4]').prop('checked', true);
```

I know using index like  `q[0]` could work, but is there any way that no need to hardcode it? Because I don't know how many values will be in this collection.

Can anyone help me with this??
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yep, you can use a loop. Have you looped over an array before? Is the issue that this one is a string `"5,1,3,4"` instead of an array `[5, 1, 3, 4]`?

Comment: Use `q.split(",")` to split your string into an array of ["5", "1", "3", "4"]

Comment: I got it! It works now =)
Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple **[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** loop to achieve this with jQuery, or **[`Array.prototype.foreach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** in vanilla JavaScript.

If you actually have a string of numbers to start off with, you'll need to split them out into an array by running **[`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** on the comma.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
// If you have a string rather than an array
const q = "5,1,3,4";
const values = q.split(",");

// If you start with an array
//const values = [5, 1, 3, 4];

$(values).each(function(index, value) {
  $('input[data-value=' + value + ']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-value="1">
<input type="checkbox" data-value="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-value="3">
<input type="checkbox" data-value="4">
<input type="checkbox" data-value="5">
```

Comment: If there’s `const`, there’s `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: Absolutely, and that would certainly be an alternative! The question mentions jQuery, so I went with `.each()`, but I'll update the answer to cover that as well :)

Comment: Yes, this is the function I use.
Thanks for the tutorial :)

Answer (score 5):

Split `q` to an array with comma and loop through each value to select the `input` you want and change the `prop`

```
q.split(",").forEach(function(value){
    $('input[data-value='+ value +']').prop('checked', true);
})
```